# no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.io.InputStream] and content type [text/csv]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-io

I am using RestTemplate to call a rest service which returns csv file which size is big. I used the below code. I am trying to store the response in a file.

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

```
String fileName =  "response.csv";
File file = new File(fileName);
Path filePath = file.toPath();

HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
InputStream responseStream = restTemplate
        .exchange(serviceURL/LogFile"), HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, InputStream.class).getBody();
try {
    Files.copy(responseStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting this exception.

**RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.io.InputStream] and content type [text/csv]**

As per my understanding we need to write suitable message converters and add/register will rest template.

**How to write suitable converter to get the csv response and store in a file?**

Comment: that's works:String response = new RestTemplate().exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class).getBody();

Comment: I tried this. It is also working but getting outofmemory error as the response is big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could download large file with below process:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String FILE_URL = "serviceURL/LogFile";
    File file = restTemplate.execute(FILE_URL, HttpMethod.GET, null, clientHttpResponse -> {
        File ret = File.createTempFile("download", ".csv");
        StreamUtils.copy(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), new FileOutputStream(ret));
        return ret;
    });
    String fileName =  "response.csv";
    File destFile = new File(fileName);
    FileUtils.copyFile(file, destFile);
```

for FileUtils you need to add **"commons-io:commons-io:2.15.1"** dependency

Comment: It is working as expected